# Add object to Unity Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity animator for a humanoid character(with multiple animations), who is sitting at a desk typing and moving a mouse around in one of those animations. The actual mouse and keyboard are not part of the animation itself, only the humanoid movements are.

The keyboard can be static in position, but the mouse has to move around with the animation's right hand, when the animation moves its hand.

Is there any way to achieve that through Unity ? How is this best handled ? Any video resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Could you attach the mouse to the hand bone when specific animation is running? Maybe this could help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1jM29vTFJE

Comment: I have actually been able to attach the mouse to the animation's right hand. But the problem is that the mouse shouldn't be attached to the hand, since the hand should at times remove on its own, while leaving the mouse to rest on the mousepad.

Comment: @Spyros add an event to detach the mouse in the animation, and then a new event to reattach it

Comment: @Eddge Oh, didn't know about those events. I think that will work yes, will try it out shortly.